# How to append an ID with the value from another ID in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I need to grab the value of an id and attach it to the end of a url on my form. Here's the html code for the input...

```
<input id="ServiceRequestEditForm.CustomObject6 Id" type="hidden" value="" tabindex="-1" name="ServiceRequestEditForm.CustomObject6 Id"/>
```

I want to capture the value of this input. I am trying to use the following code, but it doesn't work...

```
$("a[href*='http://www.google.com']").attr('href', 
('http://www.google.com/search?q'+('Form.CustomObject6 Id').val()));
```

Could someone please help me to get this working.

Comment: whose id do you want to grab `div`, `form` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `id` attribute of an element by using the `attr()` function:

```
var myId = $('Form.CustomObject6').attr('id');
```

So, assuming you need the id of `Form.CustomObject6`, this is probably what you are looking for:

```
$("a[href*='http://www.google.com']").attr('href',
    ('http://www.google.com/search?q'+ $('#ServicerequestEditForm.CustomObject6 Id').attr('id')));
```

Provide a sample of your HTML if you still aren't able to capture the `id` you need.

**EDIT**: I re-read your question and think I misunderstood what you are asking for. I think you are trying to get the value of the `ServiceRequestEditForm.CustomObject6 Id` element, but it keeps returning `undefined`.  This is because the jQuery selector contains special characters (`.` and space).  You have to escape each special character with two backslashes: `\\`.  Try this:

```
var myVal = $('#ServiceRequestEditForm\\.CustomObject6\\ Id').val();
```

So your code now becomes:

```
$("a[href*='http://www.google.com']").attr('href',
    ('http://www.google.com/search?q'+ $('#ServiceRequestEditForm\\.CustomObject6\\ Id').val()));
```

Comment: @Jack - oops, copied from th OP and didn't see it was missing.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't get the Id normally, had this problem with normal javascript too.

var myId = $('ServicerequestEditForm.CustomObject6 Id').attr('id');
      alert(myId);

This returns undefined, how else can I get at it?

Comment: Your selector is incorrect.  When selecting by id, you need to prefix the id with `#`.  Edited my answer.

Comment: Using this code I still receive an "undefined" as part of the URL. Is there another way to find the value I need without an ID?

Comment: @user961437 - I re-read your question and think I now understand what you are asking for.  I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Rocco, those backslashes are going to save me so much grief on this project!

Comment: @user961437 - Glad to hear it. Please

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href*="http://google.com"]').attr('href','http://google.com/search?q'+$('#someID').attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand, but something like this?

```
$('#'+el.id).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[href*='http://www.google.com']").attr('href', 
'http://www.google.com/search?q'+$('element').attr("id"));
```